# Custom fonts not working from CSS online webpage

Tags: html, fonts

My blog is using a custom font.

**CSS:**

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'MTCORSVA';
src: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdaq9exo0xrvug2/MTCORSVA.eot?dl=0');
src: local('MTCORSVA'), url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojzp5atilxg5idw/MTCORSVA.woff?dl=0') format('woff'), url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6ugd9yxd1jaj8b/MTCORSVA.ttf?dl=0') format('truetype');}
```

**CSS Class:**

```
.fontsforweb_fontid_6771 {
font-family: 'MTCORSVA' !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
 <html>
<head>
<link href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q3hppu5m77ylyi/font.css?dl=0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="fontsforweb_fontid_6771">
Hello, This is the Corsiva font
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any changes in my font, but I am getting when all the files are in the same server

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9i2oeuueryozlbs/font1.css)

Comment: I had also tried on the above CSS file by providing direct link to the font files

Comment: '<link href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9i2oeuueryozlbs/font1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Dropbox is sending you the font file with MIME type text/html.

If you check the console, you will see:

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6ugd9yxd1jaj8b/MTCORSVA.ttf".

So, the browser is not able to render the font that you want.

You should consider hosting the font locally or remote server.

Comment: thanx @rahul ,and could you pls explain me how to edit the mime type when using a remote server.

Comment: @AliAkbar host your font file on something like Apache server, not some service like Dropbox/Google Drive. It will definitely work if hosted in a Apache server. I am using it since long time.

Answer (score 0):

Please add stylesheet where you call the class.

```
.fontsforweb_fontid_6771 {
    font-family: 'MTCORSVA' !important;
}
```

or call Css in head section.